# COM method return correct value only when it invoked with pause intervals

Tags: c++, com, sleep, safearray

I have COM object, which I initialize it at once:

```
ISTIPositionPtr _position;

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
_position.CreateInstance(__uuidof(STIPosition));
```

Next I have function, that invoke method of this COM object:

```
LPSAFEARRAY saValues;
structSTIPositionUpdate* pVals;
long count;
float sum = 0;  

if (SUCCEEDED(_position->GetPositionList(&saValues, &count))) {
    if (SUCCEEDED(SafeArrayAccessData(saValues, (void**)&pVals))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            sum += pVals[i].fDollarsBot;
        }
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(saValues);
    }
    SafeArrayDestroy(saValues);
}

return sum;
```

Problem is that the method:

```
 _position->GetPositionList(&saValues, &count)
```

Return correct value or zero. but if I invoke function with pause intervals, then all works fine. I don't know, probably this is asynchronous method and I must use some mechanisms, that wait until method will be finished?

For example:

```
long count = 0;
while (count == 0) {
    _position->GetPositionList(&saValues, &count)
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you are using, but based just on the name of the structure `STIPositionUpdate`, could it be that `GetPositionList` returns changes (to something) since last time it's called? Then `count==0` simply indicates that no changes have in fact occurred since last time - a perfectly valid outcome. Naturally, this outcome is the more likely the more often you call the method.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, GetPositionList don't return changes since last call. This method returns list of the opened positions on the trading platform and if positions list don't changed then it must return the same result. But it always return correct result when I use Sleep(1000), after calling this method. But if I call this method repeatedly without pause then sometimes it return just empty array and count = 0.

Comment: Well then, I suggest you contact the vendor of the library you are using.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When I tried to use COM library with COM Interop in .NET then it worked fine. Troubles only in C++.

Comment: Perhaps inefficiencies involved in .NET COM interop provide just enough delay. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your calling code, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that is need to initialize saValues:

```
LPSAFEARRAY saValues = NULL;
```

and then all works as expected.